# PHP Session with MySQL Insert Into using bind_parm

Tags: php, mysql, session-variables, bindparam

I am simply trying to insert the variable from a session into a MySQL database and it causes it to fail. `var_dump` shows SESSIONS all there. No problem there. Why doesn't this work?

```
$job = $_SESSION['job'];

$user_id = '1';
$name = 'allie';

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO
                        requests(name,job_info,user_id) 
                        VALUES (?,?,?)");

$stmt->bind_param('sss', $name, $job, $user_id);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: is user id an integer or varchar in your table?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. Then replace `$stmt->execute();` with `if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$mysqli->error, E_USER_WARNING);}` that will help you out.

Comment: so, where are we at with this? two comments but nothing from you yet.

Answer (score 1):

see pdo [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

your parameter is incorrect:
change this:

```
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $name, $job, $user_id);
```

with this:

```
$stmt->bind_param(1, $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bind_param(2, $job, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bind_param(3, intval($user_id), PDO::PARAM_INT);
```